# Two conflicting views on $1_{[n,n+1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I need to justify whether $(f_{n})_{n}$ as a sequence of real-valued functions converges almost everywhere or not. Note that $f_{n}: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ where $f_{n}(x)=1_{[n,n+1]}(x)$. Now I have two views on this:

$1.$ $f_{n}$ converges pointwise to $0$ and thus $f_{n}(x) \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ for almost all $x$. This was my initial thought.

But then I started thinking about the fact that:

$2.$ for any $n \in \mathbb N$ we know that $\exists A_{n} \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ so that $\lambda(A_{n})=1$ where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue-Borel Measure on $\mathbb R$ and $\vert f(x)\vert \geq 1$ for all $x \in A_{n}$ and hence how can I say that it to zero almost everywhere, since there is always a part of the function of positive measure that is exactly a distance of $1$ away from the $0$ function.

Any ideas that could illuminate this for me?

Comment: The limit as $n\to\infty$ has $x$ fixed. Take, for example, $x=0.5$, then it should be obvious that $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$. And saying the limit is zero "for almost all $x$" doesn't make any sense. It *is* zero, for each and every $x$. As for the second part, you're probably just trying to say it converges pointwise, since there isn't one $N$ such that every $n>N$ and $x\in\mathbb R$ satisfies $|f_n(x)|<1$? It's unclear, as you claim to say $|f(x)|\ge1$, but $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ is equal to zero everywhere.

Comment: The question already has an answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3290690/notions-of-strong-and-weak-convergence-for-l2-mathbb-r-lambda-where-f/3290694?noredirect=1#comment6778142_3290694

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I disagree that this is a duplicate, the two questions only happen to study the same sequence. This question asks about the difference between a.e. and $L^\infty$ convergence, while the linked one asks about a.e., $L^2$ and $L^2$-weak.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sequence $(f_n)$ indeed converges pointwise to zero because  $f_n(x)\to 0$ for every $x$. That's all that pointwise convergence cares about: for each $x$, is it the case that $f_n(x)$ converges to $f(x)$? (Almost everywhere convergence asks: does the set of $x$ for which $f_n(x)$ fails to converge to $f(x)$ have zero measure? Clearly pointwise convergence implies almost everywhere convergence.)

What's interesting about this sequence is that the behavior of the $n$th function differs from the behavior of the limiting function $f(x):=0$. That is, the $n$th function has a bump, but the "final" function doesn't. In essence the bump "escapes to infinity". This phenomenon isn't limited to functions with unbounded domain. For example, the sequence of functions $g_n$ defined for $x\in[0,1]$ by $g_n(x):=nI_{(0,\frac1n)}(x)$ is a collection of rectangles, each with unit area. But you can check that $g_n$ converges to $0$ pointwise. (What happened to that unit area?!)

These examples are important because they illustrate that $\lim\int f_n$ isn't always equal to $\int\lim f_n$, i.e., you can't always interchange limits and integration. Integration theory, the next chapter after measure theory, gives a number of conditions under which that interchange is permissible.

Answer (score 4):

We do have that $f_n(x) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ for *all* $x$, without the 'almost'.
This is more than enough, because convergence almost everywhere means that the sequence converges pointwise outside of a null set.

In this particular case, the sequence converges pointwise everywhere.